# Loop quantum gravity: shape?

Tags: loop-quantum-gravity

What kind of shape of the universe is being suggested in loop quantum gravity?

From what I know LQG postulates a more or less discrete universe, rather than a continuous one.
Does this also mean that it postulates that space is finite? Like, for example in the shape of a doughnut?

Answer (score 0):

No, the point-wise-connected space lattice in LQG (at least as described by Lee Smolin, one of its inventors) does not close up on itself. I do not know if it is *possible* for that to be the case; perhaps one of the experts here can weigh in on this aspect of it.